# Change location of gvimrc file on Windows?

Tags: gvim

Is there a way to configure gvim to look in a different location for gvimrc?  I know about -U but I'm curious if there's another method.

EDIT:  I'm specifically looking for a self contained solution.  I.e. something like a gvim_init file in the program directory.

Comment: Personally I would just leave gvimrc in the default location and source a file in it that had the settings that I wanted.

Comment: The default location on windows can't be written to because of UAC.  It also attempts to write to the user folder instead of the user settings folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.  You simply go to the directory vim is installed in.  Create _gvimrc and set the first line:

```
source $HOME . "\\AppData\Roaming\\_gvimrc"
```

The $HOME ev is the user directory by default. You can also set runtime environment variables to give each user their own vimfiles directory this way.

Answer (score 3):

Vim's `:help startup` describes the various places vim and gvim look for configuration files. Executing `:version` will also show you the places your particular Vim will look for configuration files. If none of those places is what you want, you might try setting the environment variable MYVIMRC to your desired location. Alternatively, you could set the environment variable VIMINIT or EXINIT to source the desired gvimrc. (See `:help VIMINIT`.)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I updated my question to be more precise but I'll upvote.

Comment: @Amaron: Thanks for the vote. Clarifying the question is not really going to help, though. All the possibilities are in the help file containing the `:help startup` entry.

Comment: The :help startup says it applies to vim and not gvim?

Comment: The term "vim" is used sometimes to mean Vim operating in terminal mode and sometimes to mean the program generically. `:help startup` applies to both terminal vim and GUI gvim except where it discusses some terminal-only or GUI-only behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the end of `_vimrc`:

```
if has("gui_running")
  source C:/custom/path/to/_gvimrc
endif
```